# System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I'm using `Visual Studio 2010`. I'm reading .`NET WebForms` tutorial and trying to experimenting with `Entities`. As said in the [Create Data Access layer](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create_the_data_access_layer) I've pasted the following code in the just created class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WingtipToys.Models
{
  public class Product
  {
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(10000), Display(Name = "Product Description"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Price")]
    public double? UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
  }
}
```

But I have an error discripted as

> Error 1 The type or namespace name 'DataAnnotations' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'System.ComponentModel' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?

How to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164717/the-type-or-namespace-name-dataannotations-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-sy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution explorer -> Add reference -> Select .Net tab -> select System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations from the list